# Select returns wrong value on initial change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, html-select

I'm using React, jQuery, and NewsAPI.  The request and state should change when the user updates the option selected.  However, when the Onchange function executes it returns the wrong value. After the function executes again the value is off by one index. Can someone point me in the right direction without being rude :).

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import $ from 'jquery';
import Posts from './Components/Posts';
import './style/Content.scss';


class Content extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            posts: [],
            value: 'the-verge'
        }

        this.change = this.change.bind(this);
    }

    //Ajax Request
    getNews() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source='+ this.state.value + '&sortBy=latest&apiKey=' + api,
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: true,
            success: function(data) {
                this.setState({ posts: [data] }, function() {
                    console.log(data);
                })
            }.bind(this),
            error: function(xhr, status, err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        })
    }

    // Change the request depending on selected option
    change(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        this.setState({value: event.target.value});
        this.getNews();
    }

    componentWillMount(){
        this.getNews();
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.getNews();
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(){
        this.change();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="Content">
                <div className="Search">
                    <h2>It's all in one place</h2>
                    <div className="Search__wrap">
                        <select value={this.state.value} onChange={this.change}>
                            <option defaultValue value="the-verge">Tech Verge</option>
                            <option value="techcrunch">Tech Crunch</option>
                            <option value="time">Time</option>
                            <option value="bbc-sport">BBC Sport</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <Posts posts={this.state.posts} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Content;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is correct or not, but it's what is most apparent to me from skimming over the code.

One important thing about `setState` is that it is **not inherently** synchronous. Since there may be multiple `setState` calls in one function, they are batched and performed asynchronously. So it is possible that the state hasn't updated when `getNews` is called.

Solution? Pass the value *explicitly* to the `getNews` function.

```
change(event){
    event.preventDefault(event.target.value);
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
    this.getNews();
}
```

And then:

```
getNews(value) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source='+ value + '&sortBy=latest&apiKey=' + api,
        dataType: 'json',
...
```

That way you don't have to worry about the *race condition* of `setState` being finished before you can use the function.

You'll have to use `this.state.value` in `componentDidMount` or `componentWillMount`. Small tip: You only need to fetch the API on one of those, choose which one you want to use and remove the other one, it's redundant :)

Also, calling `this.change` in `componentWillReceiveProps` will trigger an error because you're not passing in an event.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Everything made sense except for using `this.state.value` in `componentDidMount`. Will you elaborate?